# Formatter class in android

Tags: android

The format method of formatter class in android,does not diplay a formatted string in table form properly in EditText,while in eclipse console it displays perfectly(all columns aligned).The string format is same in both the case.What can be the reason and the way to display it properly.

Comment: Using \t to spaces between "columns"? PS: Why not use TableLayout or GridLayout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use tabs or spaces in format strings to align text.
The Eclipse console uses a monospaced font and text might align nicely (because every character has the same width) but your device is probably using a proportional font where not all characters have the same width.

Use a more complex layout (like TableLayout) to position your UI elements.

Comment: thanks,for suggestion.I am using ListView and have successfully populated it with the database table.My question is how to add Column names of the database table to the columns generated in the ListView.

Comment: You could add a "header" to your ListView to achieve this. See this tutorial for an example: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#miscellaneous_headerfooter